# how to make a mount to a dir that will guard against writes to local filesystem

Tags: mount, remote

I am trying to make an app (on linux) that will auto mount google drives with `rclone` to upload data:

```
rclone mount LABELNAME: /tmp/1234.mnt
```

The app would then be able to have several threads process & copy files into `/tmp/1234.mnt` and cleanup by removing that dir when done.

Note doing this one by one is slower rclone copy than by mountpoint and its the way i feel is easiest to implement.

However, my fear is that if `rclone` was to die in while the app was processing, that dir would accept large files directly to `/tmp` filesystem instead of remote filesystem.  So is it possible for a directory to operate like a '/dev/null' like device which could be mounted and if not mounted fail to proceed with the copy if it became unmounted? ie it would prevent copying files if it was to become unmounted.

It would also have to be in unprivileged user.

Comment: "userspace not Superuser" I'm not sure what you're trying to say-the opposite of user space is kernel space, and the opposite of a super user is an unprivileged user. These two terms come from completely different categories. What do you exactly mean when you say "a device /dev/ like dir"? That doesn't make too much sense either! "To be mounted that works only serve as a mount point" so you want to mount something, or use it as a mount point? That's again somewhat contradictory. Please make sure you're not abusing vocabulary.

Comment: What is the sense in using `rclone mount` if your program needs to copy the files there? Just don't do that, but let your program upload the files directly; that puts you in control of the upload progress, and thus eliminates your problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller if you mean upload directly with rclone copy,  the reason is that there are multiple threads compressing and sending to that mount point.  if you were to do rclone copy directly its slower because it has to connect. thats why i create a mount point. and why im asking the question.

Comment: To your other comment,  rclone mount is a process that would be safer to mount a /dev/null type device. that would prevent files from gathering in an unmounted dir such as /tmp/mymount.  Is that clearer?  and it would have to be a non privileged user for the utility to work. hopefully that clears up the question

Comment: *rclone mount is a process that would be safer to mount a /dev/null type device.* sorry, this combination of words doesn't make sense – you don't mount a process. And you can't mount /dev/null either. *Is that clearer?* Sadly, no.

Comment: wow its roasting in here.

Comment: huh? I don't really follow…

Comment: You are roasting me badgering my question

Comment: ah! Sorry, not a native speaker, that idiom was new to me :) Really don't mean to roast anyone – just hope to understand :)

Comment: Nevermind its typical behavour on these forums now days. terrible

Comment: actually you may not understand what rclone is. if you didnt then i can understand your confusion.  rclone uses fusermount which is an ssh mount point. so looks like you are not famillar with rclone. and thats all.

Comment: Nono, I know `rclone`; I just don't understand what you mean when you say you want to mount a process, or mount something like /dev/null. And, I still think you're proverbially barking up the wrong proverbial tree (but you do very kindly so) :-) as your `rclone mount` still seems to me (and that might be a misunderstanding in my side, definitely) a detour to what you actually want to achieve: uploading files, under your definite control of the upload process to avoid stale files lying around somewhere, reusing HTTP connections as possible. And you can do that, with rclone's `rcd` and …1/2

Comment: … `rclone rc core/command command=cp -a … `. The remote control functionality is basically just sending commands in JSON to the rclone daemon started by `rclone --rc` or just `rcd`. On https://rclone.org/rc/ that whole mechanism is explained. 2/2